# Poem Title Off Center

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, poetry

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Photos/} }
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
} 
\usepackage{titling,lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tgcursor}

\def\CC#1{\makebox[4in]{#1}} % centres the poem lines

\begin{document}
\section{Missteps}
\poemtitle {Way Too Personal} 

\vspace{7.5mm} \begin{verse}
\CC{She believes in Love Stories}

\CC{But not her own,}

\CC{That’s way too personal}

\CC{For it to be worth}

\CC{A damn.}

\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

[image: Which shows this]

By measuring the page, you can see that the title is not perfectly centered horizontally (same this happened with the verse so it was put inside a box) and I was wondering how to fix that. If I use \hspace then the title moves around in the table of contents as well making it look messy.

Answer (score 3):

The default margins of `article` are not necessarily centered on the page, especially since LaTeX wasn't designed with a concept of page size to begin with. That said, I would note that your `\poemtitle` definition is not provided and your `\CC` macro doesn't actually center the lines, but centers them in a 4 inch box. If all your poems are to be centered, you might consider doing something like

```
\newenvironment{myverse}{\begin{verse}\centering}{\end{verse}}
```

to get the verse lines centered. I'd also incorporate the `\vspace` into the `\poemtitle` command.

In verse, lines are usually separated with `\\` and blank lines are used for stanzas. Some poets like the stanza break between every line though, so it's not clear whether this is what you wanted.